# Angularjs: slick not working properly with custom directives

Tags: angularjs

i have been trying for hours looking for a method to make a carousel to slide multiple elements instead of one, but elements that are compiled custom directives from `angularjs`, for the moment i found `slick` is the good framework that can do this job and i have tested on my local files with successful results, but when i try to load it to the server which has everything loading from cdn, browser starts to throw errors multiple times:

```
Error: a.replace is not a function
Error: w is undefined
Error: a.replace is not a function
Error: w is undefined
```

the code the page has.. is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>styles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController" layout="column" layout-fill>
    <md-content flex layout="column">
        <md-content flex>
            <div class="focusPlan">
                <div class="focus">
                    <p>Focus</p>
                </div>
                <div class="plans">
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="focusPlan">
                <div class="focus">
                    <p>Focus</p>
                </div>
                <div class="plans">
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="focusPlan">
                <div class="focus">
                    <p>Focus</p>
                </div>
                <div class="plans">
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="focusPlan">
                <div class="focus">
                    <p>Focus</p>
                </div>
                <div class="plans">
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                    <card-plans button="Get"></card-plans>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </md-content>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../cards/people/people-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="../cards/plans/plans-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="../cards/events/events-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="../sections/blogs/blogs-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="../sections/posts/posts-directive.js"></script>

    <script>
        /*
         * Angular's application instance
         */
        (function(angular, $){
            var app = angular.module("test", ["ngMaterial", "test-directives"]);

            app.config(["$mdThemingProvider", "$mdIconProvider", function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider){
                $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                    .primaryPalette('light-blue',{
                        'default':'400'
                    });

                $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet("mdi.svg");
            }]);

            app.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$mdSidenav", function($scope, $sidenav){
                $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
                    $sidenav("menu").toggle();
                };

                $(".plans").slick({
                    infinite: true,
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3
                });

                $scope.gridMode = false;
            }]);
        })(angular, $);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in this view i only have 1 custom directive called multiple times which is `<card-plans>` and it actually contains little logic with template.

without slick the items look like this:
[image: directive list]

and all i want is just to have a carousel to scroll multiple elements instead of 1 by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like kind of init sequance problems.

Wrap your slick logic into separate directive with transclusion using postlink function

```
.directive('carousel', function(){
    return function(){
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            el.append(transclude());
            elem.children().slick(/*stuff*/);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function(){/* slick destroy*/});
        }
    };
});

<carousel>
   <card-plans></card-plans>
   ....
</carousel>
```

Comment: I didn't know i had to use transclusion, to be honest i don't know how to use transclusion so i used part of your code to make it work.. thanks alot, now i really want to learn good tricks about transclusion